# Send push notifications to reminders

Tags: mongodb, meteor, push-notification

somebody could point me some information as to implement the activation of the reminder, for example in the image I establish the hour and frequentia in which I want to repeat the reminder (daily, weekly, monthly, without repetition) There I must make the query to know when the period expires which was scheduled the reminder and thereinididicar with a push notification that said reminder was culminated.

The detail I present is to query the mongo when the app is closed the query can not be performed to verify the status of the reminder. Think about doing background mode with hybrid: background, but maybe it can affect the battery consumption of the phone because of the amount of reminders the user can create, they will constantly be consulted on the state of the app.

If someone has a method I thank you for pointing me some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a `cron` to initiate an action after x units of time.

In `meteor` you can use this cron [package](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron).

As higlighted in the docs, you can schedule a task to launch after certain time, or after every x mins or so.

```
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Crunch some important numbers for the marketing department',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object
    return parser.text('every 2 hours');
  },
  job: function() {
    var numbersCrunched = CrushSomeNumbers();
    return numbersCrunched;
  }
});
```

Once the task is triggered, you can send a push notification from the server to the client app. This will work even when the app is off, as the jobs are done on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the help I will read about it to see how this works for me.